# Can't Fix Flipped Image Texture

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I'm not sure what's happening, I've followed tutorials, but nothing seems to work. Here you can see that my UV looks intact, and I believe I've set up my material accordingly. Yet I can't seem to get the image texture to flip.

I know the UV isn't scaled correctly, but i have scaled it perfectly before and it still didn't work.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the _UV Editor_ just hit S, X, -1, Enter to flip the UVs on the X axis or use Y instead of X to flip on X axis. Or hit R, 180, Enter to rotate it upside down. Whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Your Texture Coordinates node has to use UV socket not Generated. BTW ... If your screen is in just flat X axis you can Unwrap from View to keep proportions right.

Comment: Exactly. The _Generated_ space will completely ignore your UV mapping. It's 0->1 from min->max X,Y and Z of the object's own space, whatever.

Comment: *UV Map* texture space is implied by the *Image Texture* node, so all you have to do is to delete your left-most node.